# Jibri recording issues behind reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, jitsi-meet

I'm trying to run Jibri as part of a Jitsi-Meet installation (all on one server) behind a reverse SSL proxyJitsi works out of the box, but as soon as Jibri tries to log in to the session to record it, the corresponding Chrome session times out. Here's an excerpt from the jibri log:

```
2021-04-04 09:09:42.546 FINE: [890] org.jitsi.jibri.selenium.pageobjects.CallPage.visit() Visiting url https://example.com/room#config.iAmRecorder=true&config.externalConnectUrl=null&config.startWithAudioMuted=true&config.startWithVideoMuted=true&interfaceConfig.APP_NAME="Jibri"&config.analytics.disabled=true&config.p2p.enabled=false&config.prejoinPageEnabled=false&config.requireDisplayName=false
2021-04-04 09:09:42.633 FINE: [890] org.jitsi.jibri.selenium.pageobjects.CallPage.apply() Not joined yet: APP is not defined
...
2021-04-04 09:10:12.945 INFO: [890] org.jitsi.jibri.selenium.JibriSelenium.onSeleniumStateChange() Transitioning from state Starting up to Error: FailedToJoinCall SESSION Failed to join the call
2021-04-04 09:10:12.947 INFO: [890] org.jitsi.jibri.service.impl.FileRecordingJibriService.onServiceStateChange() File recording service transitioning from state Starting up to Error: FailedToJoinCall SESSION Failed to join the call
```

The reverse proxy is configured to watch out for this login string on port 443 (normal SSL traffic per the URL above) and forward this to the Jitsi instance. Prosody accepts the request on its http-bind interface but then the invocation times out.

As the web server logs are inconclusive: Where / what logs can I check to see what happens afterwards? I can see jicofo picking up the invocation but don't know what happens afterwards (`Jicofo 2021-04-04 09:09:42.130 INFO: [461] org.jitsi.jicofo.recording.jibri.JibriSession.log() Updating status from JIBRI: <iq to='focus@auth.example.com/focus647288887711795' from='jibribrewery@internal.auth.example.com/jibri-nickname' id='5iurC-49012' type='result'><jibri xmlns='http://jitsi.org/protocol/jibri' status='pending'/></iq> for room@conference.example.com`)?

More than happy to provide more info as required.